# Memory usage high on server compared to wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, server

Lately my site (with 260000 posts, 12000 images, 2,360,987 mysql rows and 450.7 MiB size) is running slow and at times not loading for many mins

I installed this Debug bar plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/

Memory usage

**on server is**: 174,319,288 bytes

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz , 16 GB
(PHP: 5.5.23, MySQL: 5.6.23, Apache 2.4)

Even tried disabling all plugins it doesnt help much... it comes down 160-163,xxx,xxx bytes

**on wamp is** : 37,834,920 bytes

(PHP: 5.5.12, MySQL: 5.6.17)

Why the difference is huge? How to detect the problem?

Been using the following plugins

Acunetix WP Security
Akismet
Antispam Bee
CloudFlare
Contact Form 7
Custom Post Type UI
Debug Bar
Login LockDown
Redirection
Theme Test Drive
W3 Total Cache
WordPress SEO
WP-Optimize
WP Missed Schedule

my.cnf values for the above server are

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log=1
long-query-time=1
slow-query-log-file="/var/log/mysql-slow.log"
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
local-infile = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

max_connections=360
wait_timeout=60
connect_timeout = 15

thread_cache_size=20
thread_concurrency=8

key_buffer_size = 1024M
join_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size=1M

query_cache_limit=64M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_type=1

max_heap_table_size=32M
tmp_table_size=32MB
table_open_cache=1000
table_definition_cache=1024

open_files_limit=10000

max_allowed_packet=268435456


low_priority_updates=1
concurrent_insert=2


#port = 8881
#innodb_force_recovery=0
#innodb_purge_threads=0
```

Comment: Did you leave wamp running for a while and provide it with the same amount (and kind) of traffic as the other?

Comment: Tried restarting the server and checked it in initial moments

Comment: From my point of view that seems like a very small amount of memory being used, even on the server. Sure, there's ~ 130MB difference between the two, but your server using 174 mb of ram hardly seems likely to cause problems. You should attempt to diagnose where the slowdown is actually happening. Is it network related? server related? if it's server related, Is any one pid using more resources than expected? (cpu or ram) If you find it to be network related, contact your host.

Comment: Do you have the same PHP Versions? And is really all the same? Did you test with a dump of your live db?

Comment: @Stony i backed up the whole site and restored on wamp and tried checking it.

And the php versions are disclosed above... My PC is running on i7 4770 @ 3.4GHz with 8GB ram

Comment: @KevinB from daily logs in WHM i can only see the mysql hits abt 10-12% memory mark and corresponding cpanel user 7-8 % CPU

Is there any option to check whats running bad.

Comment: yes, but i think that's a bit too advanced for stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is for programming problems, not server administration. Try server fault.

Comment: ok will post same on SF

Comment: If using InnoDB, what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If using MyISAM, what is the value of `key_buffer_size`?

Comment: @RickJames here it is innodb_buffer_pool_size=200M

Answer (score 0):

The "server" has Apache; that accounts for some (all?) of the difference.

Windows and Unix handle memory differently, and measure it differently.  So, the difference may be irrelevant.

The numbers you have quoted are not big; what is the problem?

"Tried restarting the server and checked it in initial moments" -- That's mostly irrelevant.  Programs tend to grow over time, up to some limit.  Let's see the values in "steady state" with a typical load.

You have enough RAM to cache the entire dataset in RAM.  But, due to inactivity, probably most of the data is not touched, hence has not been read into cache.

"High" memory usage is when you are swapping.  Actually, that is probably "too high".  So, say, 90% is "high".  Your numbers are nowhere near that.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size=200M` -- is not enough to hold the entire 450.7MB dataset, but, as I say, most of the data is probably not actively used.

**Edit (after posting of settings)**

```
table_cache=10M
```

That is terrible!  You won't be opening 10 million tables.  Set it to 1000.

```
max_heap_table_size=512M
tmp_table_size=512MB
```

Those are dangerous.  If you have multiple connections, each needing a tmp table (because of a complex query), you could run out of memory fast.  Set them down to 32M.

```
innodb_force_recovery=3
```

Comment out that line -- It is to be used once, then removed.

The rest of the settings look harmless for this discussion.

Comment: The problem i am facing is that all of a sudden at one point the server becomes unresponsive (have to wait too long or do a restart through host control panel) and nothing works (site, whm, ssh)...

The load avg gets to 250+ on this server

Something like Load Averages: 251.42 261.23 279.09

Comment: added my.cnf values to post above... kindly look at them and suggest me as most of my installs are wordpress

Comment: Aha.  Load Average = 250 is terrible.  Now, if I could only remember what caused it.  Perhaps something on the _client_ got caught in a loop, creating more and more connections.  Suggest having "top" running in a window and hope that next time it happens, "top" output will be still visible and useful for finding the culprit.

Comment: I don't think MySQL is to blame.  Even if MySQL is at the top of "top", it is the _client(s)_ that need to be investigated.

Comment: Can't see when it occurs but all of sudden it gets that high... once i was able on whm when it was unresponsive as saw load increase to that high...

I added my old my.cnf previously which i used when i got mysql not loading... now added the correct one with your suggestions.